# Cycles: Assign material to vertex group

Tags: shaders, vertex-groups

I know it's possible to have multiple shaders for one object with the internal renderer. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvAFUywSFbw) explains the process.

Can I use Cycles to assign a material to a vertex group so that a single object may have multiple materials? If so, how?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/599

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It works exactly the same, just press the "Assign" button with the desired vertex-groups/faces selected. Unassigned geometry uses the default (first) material slot.