# Cycles multiple material and multiple importance sample light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, vertex-colors

I'm having a problem with multiple materials and multiple importance sample options on the light.

I make a vertex color to assign the different material to the vertex. Node setup is in the screenshot. Also, I choose the multiple importance sample option on the sun lamp.

The problem is the shadow from invisible part of the prism.
I need to make a shadow only from a visible part. Also, there is no way to call a vertex group by name, only by color, right?

[image]

Comment: Make sure *transparent shadows* is enabled in *Properties > Material > Settings*, and that *Shadows* is enabled in *Render settings > Light paths*. Also note that you can directly assign separate materials to different faces, which might be want you want. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9292/599

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
The problem was in zero difuse reflection bounces in Light Paths settings.

Comment: Yep, that would do it too. Glad you found the answer :) Feel free to post it in an answer below so this can be marked as answered, making it easier for others with the same issue to find. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there were zero diffuse reflection bounces. This value can be set in the Light Paths settings.